# How do I fix .rbenv version with bundle install error in Jekyll? Reason: image not found

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I keep getting this error: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError).  I'm not sure how to fix this error.  Apologies, I'm new to working with Jekyll and ruby.

```
Last login: Thu Feb 13 14:14:27 on ttys000
FVFY14QJHV2D:~ User$ cd /Users/User/Documents/honoring 
FVFY14QJHV2D:honoring User$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Could not find public_suffix-4.0.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
FVFY14QJHV2D:honoring User$ bundle install
Traceback (most recent call last):
    33: from /.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    32: from /.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    31: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/exe/bundle:34:in `<top (required)>'
    30: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:123:in `with_friendly_errors'
    29: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/exe/bundle:46:in `block in <top (required)>'
    28: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
    27: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:476:in `start'
    26: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
    25: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:399:in `dispatch'
    24: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    23: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    22: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:255:in `install'
    21: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/settings.rb:124:in `temporary'
    20: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:256:in `block in install'
    19: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:54:in `run'
    18: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    17: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    16: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:11:in `<module:Bundler>'
    14: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:221:in `<class:Fetcher>'
    13: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    12: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    11: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/fetcher/index.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     9: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     8: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     5: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/s3_uri_signer.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     3: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     2: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/openssl.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Users/User/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users//.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
FVFY14QJHV2D:honoring User$ rvm list
-bash: rvm: command not found
FVFY14QJHV2D:honoring User$
```

Comment: please describe your question, and try to give some steps to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited my question

Comment: Probably easiest to remove Ruby, remove rbenv, reinstall OpenSSL through `brew install openssl`, then reinstall rbenv, then reinstall Ruby, then re-run `bundle install`.

Comment: This worked!  Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Bit late here, but might help someone in future. plase make sure that you have javascript client install in your matchine, if in your project if node.js please inatall nvm first then run `bundler install` it will works.